# Realizar petición POST con librería Axios, como añadir "params" a la petición

Tags: nodejs, rest, post, axios, postman

soy nuevo en NodeJS, estoy intentando hacer una peticion POST, pero cada vez que lo intento me devuelve un error eterno Axios. Este es el error que me devuelve y atrapo en el catch de mi petición POST que ahora veréis debajo:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 443,
  config: {
    url: 'url?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"params":{"client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx","client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.0',
      'Content-Length': 115
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
  },
  request: Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'https:',
      path: 'url?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=xxxxxxxxxxx',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: null,
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: 'url',
      search: '?client_id=xxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=xxxxxxxxxx'
    },
    _ended: false,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 115,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [ [Object] ],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: false,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST url?client_id=xxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.0\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 115\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: 'url?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      _redirectable: [Circular],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'url?client_id=xxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=xxxxxxxxxxx',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Aquí os dejo mi petición post:

```
const token = async() => {
    axios.post("url?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=xxxxxxxxxxxxx", {
            params: {
                client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                client_secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                grant_type: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
};
```

Pretendo simular la misma petición que realizo a través de Postman y si me funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Únicamente inserto los params a través de postman, los 7 headers que aparecen en la imagen son los autogenerados por postman.

¿Alguien ve la solución al problema? Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un trozo de un proyecto que tengo donde uso Axios con parámetros para métodos post.

```
axios.get(BASE_URL + "login", {
          params: {
            username: username.trim(),
            password: password.trim(),
          },
        }).then(...);
```

Edit: Acabo de ver lo del error, lo que te dice ahí es que no está bien configurado el CORS para tu proyecto, pero sí para PostMan, por lo que añade esto a tu app.js (al menos, el mío es así).

```
var cors = require("cors");
...
app.use(cors());
```

Yo ahí permito cualquier petición (GET/PÒST/UDATE/DELETE) a mi backend desde cualquier origen. Si quieres modificar eso y permitir sólo de ciertos orígenes, te adjunto un [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) con más información.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Sergio, veo que eso es una petición get, a pesar de que yo estoy realizando una peticion post, el formato veo que es idéntico, ¿sabes si actúan igual las peticiones post y get a la hora de declarar sus params¿? Un saludo

Comment: Te he editado el mensaje porque he visto que tu problema parece ser de CORS, revísalo de nuevo. Un saludo.

Te dejo un [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501185/how-to-post-query-parameters-with-axios) con otro hilo de SO en inglés donde tenían el mismo problema que tú.